# Curve fitting to distorted Gaussian

Tags: gaussian

I have to measure the distance between two pulse trains, each of which looks like a slightly long tailed Gaussian distribution. Is there a relatively easy curve fitting method for this? I can do it with the required accuracy if the distribution does not have a prominent tail.

[As an aside, autocorrelation using FFTs is not good enough]

Comment: It would be nice if you could post a picture, or a potential model for your peaks.